# How to convert a Numpy matrix into a Sympy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy

I have constructed a randomly generated matrix of a specified size and that part works great. Give it a row and column size and boom a matrix of whole numbers from 0 to 100. More recently I tried to perform a sympy operation to a numpy matrix and python kept crashing on me. I soon learned that operations from sympy could not work on a numpy matrix. So I looked into how to convert a numpy into a sympy, but more often than not I have only found sympy into numpy using lambdify. I was wondering if I could use lambdify still to convert from numpy to sympy however. Here is the code I have

```
import math
import numpy as SHIT
import sympy as GARBAGE
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function
from sympy import Function
import __future__
import __init__
# init_print(use_unicode=True)

alpha = eval(input("How many rows? "))
beta = eval(input("How many columns? "))

def make_matrix(alpha,beta):
    matrix_thing = SHIT.random.randint(0,50,(alpha,beta))
    return(matrix_thing)
print(make_matrix(alpha,beta))

matrix_thing_sympy = lambdify(alpha,beta,make_matrix(alpha,beta), SHIT)
```

Traceback: Argument must be either a string, dict or module but it is: [24 11]
FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if modname in modlist:

The [24 11] you see was from a randomly generated 2 by 2 matrix. So if lambdify is reading this row by row, how is this not a string of numbers? This is the string: 24, 11. But python doesn't seem to agree with me on that.

I have varied the statement of the final line to the following, none have worked.

```
matrix_thing_sympy = lambdify(alpha,beta,make_matrix, SHIT)
```

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'doprint'

```
matrix_thing_sympy = lambdify((alpha,beta),make_matrix(alpha,beta), SHIT)
```

VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  rational=rational) for x in a])

lambda 2,2: ([[17  6]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

More importantly to me is, why won't this just work by default? I had figured if a matrix were a matrix that it is a matrix and who cares about if it were made using numpy sympy or any py for that matter. I digress but maybe this isn't a half bad point for me to understand as well.

Comment: Can you use `alpha` and `beta` without `alpha, beta = symbols('alpha beta')`?

Comment: I'm sorry I am not quite following, how do you mean?

Comment: `alpha, beta = symbols('alpha');print(type(alpha));<class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>`

Comment: Sympy lambdify needs `Symbol` class, not an integer.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html , http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/numeric-computation.html

Comment: so pretty much i need to write 

`alpha, beta=symbols('alpha beta')`

I tried that and put that back into matrix thing sympy and now it tells me it cannot convert expression to float. They are whole numbers, why trip over about floating or not? I tried to set the``dtype=byte` and `dtype = float` and neither worked.

Comment: I am not sure you can make a *NumPy* matrix with arbitrary size. Try *SymPy* `Matrices`

Comment: as in `from sympy.matrices import *`?

it says the same cannot convert expression to float. More interestingly, reading through the error it gave me some lines i've never seen before

`mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:14756)()`

`mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.randint (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:14581)()`

`mtrand.pyx in mtrand._rand_int32 (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:9690)()`

Does that help any?

Comment: More fundamentally, is there any reason using a symbol in generating matrix? Generally, symbol is used in equation solving. Does your work needs a size of matrix as a part of equation?

Comment: Fundamentally I wanted to make a matrix of some specified size with randomly generated whole numbers elements that I could perform a Reduced Row Echelon Form algorithm that I found Sympy had an extension for. So there is some equation solving soon to happen.

Comment: No, I mean, even if you symbolize the dimensions of a matrix, RREF cannot be represented in a closed for with respect to the dimensions.

Comment: love the obscenities! I gotta start coding like that :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Perform `sympy.Matrix(numpy_matrix)`

From comments, I suggest this

## Converting NumPy matrix to SymPy matrix

```
import math
import numpy as SHIT
import sympy as GARBAGE
from sympy import *
from sympy import Matrix
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify, implemented_function
from sympy import Function
import __future__
import __init__
# init_print(use_unicode=True)

alpha = eval(input("How many rows? "))
beta = eval(input("How many columns? "))

def make_matrix(alpha,beta):
    matrix_thing = SHIT.random.randint(0,50,(alpha,beta))
    return(matrix_thing)

matrix_sympy = Matrix(make_matrix(alpha, beta)) # use sympy.Matrix()
```

After then

```
matrix_sympy.rref()
```

## Alternatively,

NumPy also has RREF (strictly speaking, SciPy does)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la

def make_matrix(alpha,beta):
    matrix_thing = np.random.randint(0,50,(alpha,beta))
    return(matrix_thing)

matrix_numpy = make_matrix(alpha, beta)
(_, rref) = la.qr(matrix_numpy) # perform QR decomposition, R is RREF
```

Both methods don't require symbolic variable. NumPy is not a SHIT thing.

## When to use SymPy

Generally, you need SymPy when you want to find a general solution which is represented with a arbitrary variable without specific values.

```
import sympy
x = symbols('x a b c')
y = a * x ** 2 + b * x + c # generall quadratic equation.
sympy.solve(y, x)
```

output:

```
[(-b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a), -(b + sqrt(-4*a*c + b**2))/(2*a)]
```

In your example, there is no space for RREF to be represented with respect to `alpha` and `beta`

Comment: Please forgive my obscenities, I will try this thank you.

Comment: for the numpy it works great and i didn't know that they had a linear algebra stuffs. Now as for sympy I still don't quite understand what you mean by alpha and beta. Those were just used as place holders to construct a matrix, not as a means of symbolic variables. Thank you for your thoroughness @Jeon

Comment: In short, it seems that sympy can't make a matrix with undetermined dimensions.

Comment: Also the result of the `(_, rref())` comes out with 2 matrices, how come?

Comment: And no `rref()`, `rref`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fwtsUH58 here is a paste bin of the code. Modified with less (none) obscene language.